# How to load only the first related data with EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

i have got an issue that i identified as that:

let's suppose these objects.

```
public class Order{
    int id{get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
}


public class OrderItem{
    int id{get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}
    public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
}

public class User{
    int id{get;set;}
    string name {get;set;}

}
```

So the problem is when i tried to get an query like this

```
context.Order
.Where(pre => pre.Id == Id)
.OrderByDescending(pre => pre.Id)
.Skip(( pageNumber - 1 ) * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize)
.Include(pre => pre.OrderItem)
.Select(pre => new
  {
    pre.name,
    pre.OrderItem
  }).ToList()
```

All the problem happens with the include OrderItem, when i get it on select the orderItem come with all their related data.

My final object became like it:

```
{
  name,
  OrderItem :{
    name,
    Order : {
     Id,
     name,
     User: {
       name,
       Id
     }
    }
  }
}
```

but what i want is just the name and orderItem:

```
{
  name,
  OrderItem :{
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: That was just an approximation of the problem, please ignore the classes and query

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on @kit's comment, then one solution could be:

```
context.Order
.Where(pre => pre.Id == Id)
.OrderByDescending(pre => pre.Id)
.Skip(( pageNumber - 1 ) * pageSize)
.Take(pageSize)
.Include(pre => pre.OrderItem)
.Select(pre => new
  {
    pre.name,
    OrderItem = new {
      pre.OrderItem.name
    }
  }).ToList()
```